# How to render rails partial into a new browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I render a rails _partial.html.erb into a new browser tab?

Let me explain:

I have a Ruby on Rails MVC CRUD with a simple form within new.html.erb, which user fill almost 25 fields and submit a form.

Inside the controller there's a **create** method, defined to create everything into database and then invoke a method to send this document to the printer..

In order to do that, inside the **create** method it's rendering a html template view which content is a lot of variables being printed with a pretty html+css template... and then on document ready it calls window.print() via javascript.

It's working fine but I would like to change this behaviour. I want that when new.html.erb submits the form, active tab gets redirected back to documents index (*it's ok for me up to here*) and the document, which will be printed, open rendering in a new tab, focused.

Current solution is:

```
def create
  ... # lots of commands here
  render partial: 'contracts/printer/contract_template'
end
```

How can I code this last doubt: ..."*the document, which will be printed, open rendering in a new tab, focused.*" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add option `target="_blank"` to your form, this will make make your form submitted on new tab and on that tab it will render whatever you defined in `create` method.

Then write a script to listen to that form `onSubmit` and then redirect the current page to index.

```
$('#your-form-id').submit(function() {
    window.location.href = "YOUR_INDEX_PAGE";
});
```

Comment: Thank you Long Nguyen. It's working fine. Once i'm using rails form_helpers, I've used `<%= form_for(@contract, :html => {:target=>'_blank'}, :url=> {:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>` to insert `target="_blank"`.

Comment: Yes it's working, I have done exactly as you suggested... thank you very much.

Comment: @HudsonSantos cool! so please accept this answer so others can find it easier :)

Comment: Ah,  sorry,  I've clicked the green "v"  right now.  Is this the right way to accept the answer?